# I accidentally changed the IP adapter of Azure windows vm, which made it impossible for me to connect to the server remotely

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I accidentally changed the  IP adapter of Azure windows vm, which made it impossible for me to connect to the server remotely. Then I restarted the virtual machine several times on the manage console, but it didn't work. I'm going to crash.

How do I regain access to Virtual Machine?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the NIC configuration.  You can do that by changing the IP address from that Azure Portal.  See article below;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-network-interface